# Error while testing a smart contract functionality with Mocha

Tags: contract-development, mocha

I wanted to test my code functionality with the Mocha Framework, but every time it responded me with an error, not an assertion.
The specific error was:

> Error:cannot find module "ganache-cli"
> require stack:...

This is my `contract.test.js`:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(provider());

const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");

let lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" })
});

describe("Lottery contract", () => {
  it("deploys a contrcat", () => {
    assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import from `ganache-cli`, so you have to install it as  a dependency. If you're using `npm`, you can install it like:

```
npm install --save-dev ganache-cli
```

or with `yarn`:

```
yarn add -D ganache-cli
```

Comment: should i take my terminal destination to the intended folder or not ?

Comment: thank u so much for ur respond by the way

Comment: You should run this in the folder with your package.json file.